# extending angularjs form controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

I have multiple child ng-form which are part of parent ng-form, I want to set the $submitted status of all the child forms, when I set the parent ng-form to $submitted status.

As of now no such method is available on the form-controller, checked [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

Lets say, if I want to extend the current form controller to do this, how should I do that? how do I add a new method `$setChildFormsToSubmittedState()` ? of course I want to do it without disturbing/touching the angular code.

Is it possible? I think it should be given all the child forms hook into parent form using `$addControl();`.

No idea from where to start.

Comment: make a directive,and attach listener there for parent form submission..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a directive that appends a functionality to the form controller. Simply create a method that iterates over all the controls by checking if an item has a `$$parentForm` property that is equal to the form object it belongs to.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/BenmyONlOzJiySLD730K?p=preview)**

**Javascript**

```
  .directive('myForm', function() {

    return {
      require: 'form',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, form) {
        form.__setSubmitted = function() {
          setSubmitted(form);
        };

        function setSubmitted(form) {
          form.$submitted = true;
          angular.forEach(form, function(item) {
            if(item && item.$$parentForm === form) {
              setSubmitted(item);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    };

  });
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="myForm" my-form ng-submit="myForm.__setSubmitted()">
  <ng-form name="mySubForm1">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.something1" name="something">
    {{mySubForm1.$submitted}}
  </ng-form>
  <br>

  <ng-form name="mySubForm2">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.something2" name="something">
    {{mySubForm2.$submitted}}
  </ng-form>
  <br>

  <button type="submit">Button</button>
  {{myForm.$submitted}}
</form>
```

Comment: it works, just one query. why `angular.forEach(form,`. form is an object, then why do we need forEach on it?

Comment: The [**AngularJS docuemntation states**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach): `angular.forEach`, Invokes the iterator function once for each item in obj collection, which can be either an object or an array.

Comment: ok, so you mean, the `form` can sometime be collection, hence we need forEach.

Comment: The `form` controller is an object that holds a collection of `controls` and `ngModels`.